# Can I open many channels to one connection?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network

Trying to learn the Lightning Network :)

Can I do something like this:

**STEP 1: Generate new addresses**

- address_1 = cli/lightning-cli newaddr
- address_2 = cli/lightning-cli newaddr
- address_3 = cli/lightning-cli newaddr
- address_4 = cli/lightning-cli newaddr
- address_5 = cli/lightning-cli newaddr

**STEP 2: Get transaction ids**

- txnid_1 = bitcoin-cli -testnet sendtoaddress address_1 60000
- txnid_2 = bitcoin-cli -testnet sendtoaddress address_2 70000
- txnid_3 = bitcoin-cli -testnet sendtoaddress address_3 80000
- txnid_4 = bitcoin-cli -testnet sendtoaddress address_4 90000

**Question 1:** the commands above transfer money the `BITCOIN NETWORK` to the `LIGHTNNG NETWORK` - right??? If so, which BITCOIN "FROM" address is being used?

**STEP 3: See who I am connected to**

run: **cli/lightning-cli listpeers** (to see who I am connected with)

**Please note that for my example:**

- Public Key for NODE_B => is not on list above (not a peer)
- Public Key for NODE_C => is not on list above (not a peer)
- Public Key for NODE_D => is not on list above (not a peer)

**STEP 4: Fund the channels:**

The command I see for funding a channel is:  **cli/lightning-cli fundchannel**

- BUT -

**What I would like to do:**

- cli/lightning-cli fundchannel NODE_B 10000 [txnid_2]
- cli/lightning-cli fundchannel NODE_C 20000 [txnid_2]
- cli/lightning-cli fundchannel NODE_B 30000 [txnid_3]
- cli/lightning-cli fundchannel NODE_D 40000 [txnid_4]

For example I want to fund a channel to **NODE_**B with **10000** Satoshi from  **txnid_2**

**Question 2:** Is what I would like to do possible?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

> he commands above transfer money the BITCOIN NETWORK to the LIGHTNNG NETWORK - right???

No. It sends money to addresses the c-lightning can use for creating Lightning Network transactions. There is no "transfer money from Bitcoin to Lightning", they are not separate and distinct things.

> If so, which BITCOIN "FROM" address is being used?

There is no such thing as a Bitcoin from address. That is not how Bitcoin works. It may seem like there are from addresses, but that's just a simplification for users.

> Is what I would like to do possible?

No, it is currently not possible to choose what transactions to use to fund your channels with c-lightning.

Comment: thanks for the response! Above, you said: "No, it is currently not possible to choose what transactions to use to fund your channels with c-lightning." Is there any other way that this can be done? TIA